# Leray-Schauder Degree for Periodic Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, nonlinear-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Z \subset X$ a closed, linear subspace and
$$
S : U \cap Z \to X
$$
where $U \subseteq X$ is open.

**Question**: Can I define the Leray-Schauder degree of $S$? If I had $S : U \to X$ this would be fine by the usual definition, assuming all the required conditions (compactness, no fixed points on the boundary etc) are met.

**Motivation**

I'm interested in the problem
$$
u''(s) = f_t(u(s), s)
$$
for $s \in \mathbb{S}^1$ with $f_t = f(\cdot, \cdot, t)$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Assuming I can solve the problem for $f_0$, the goal is to use a degree theoretic argument to show I can solve the problem for $f_1$. The issue I am having is in defining the appropriate operators with well defined degrees.

My setting is on the Banach space, $X = C^2(\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R})$ equipped with the usual $C^2$ norm. Let $j : C^2(\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}) \to C^0(\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{R})$ be the (compact) inclusion where $C^0$ is equipped with the sup-norm. Letting $L(u) = u''$, $F_t : C^0(\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R})$ be given by $F_t(u)(s) = f(u(s), s)$, the problem becomes
$$
L(u) = F_t \circ j(u)
$$
which I rewrite as a fixed point problem
$$
u = S_t(u)
$$
with $S_t = L^{-1} \circ F_t \circ j$ which will be a compact map provided I work on a suitable domain where $L$ is invertible. For the sake of argument, we can assume that I'm working in a bounded open set $U \subseteq X$. Then the Leray-Schauder degree $\operatorname{deg}(I - S_t, U, 0)$ will be defined provided there are no fixed points on the boundary and then a solution exists if and only if $\operatorname{deg}(I - S_t, U, 0) \ne 0$.

The issue I have is with $L^{-1}$. The kernel of $L$ is the constant maps and it has a closed complement
$$
\tilde{X} = \left\{u \in X : \int u ds = 0\right\}
$$
Of course $\tilde{X}$ is precisely the range of $L$, so $L : \tilde{X} \to \tilde{X}$ is invertible self map of the Banach space $\tilde{X}$. Great!

But for $u \in \tilde{X}$, there is no reason why $F (u) \in \tilde{X}$ should be true, hence $L^{-1} \circ F$ is not defined. I could restrict to the closed set
$$
Z = F^{\ast} \tilde{X} \cap \tilde{X} = \{u : F(u) \in \tilde{X}\} \cap \tilde{X}.
$$
Then $L^{-1} \circ F$ is defined, but now
$$
S_t : Z \cap U \to \tilde{X}.
$$
which leads to my question.

Comment: But is there a way to define Leray Schauder degree on an open set in a subspace like you originally asked? For a different problem, I ran into the same issue, but I might not have a clever workaround.

Comment: In the original question, I said Z should be a closed, linear subspace but for my problem Z is not a linear subspace, but a closed subset. In that case, I'm not sure how to proceed. If Z is a closed, linear subspace that has a closed complement, and $p \in Z$ with $p \notin S(\partial U) \cap Z$ you could just define $deg(S, U, p) = deg(\pi \circ S, U, p)$ where $\pi : X \to Z$ is the (continuous) projection. Then if the degree is non-zero, there is a solution $S(x) = p$ with $x \in U \cap Z$ and presumably the degree satisfies all the usual properties. If $p \notin Z$, then I'm not sure.

Comment: In fact, the next step in my problem is to restrict to the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}$, which is a closed subset but not a closed, linear subspace. Then I get a map from $U \cap \mathbb{S} \to X$ and provided it is non-zero (in my case this is true) I can divide by the norm and get a map from an open set of $\mathbb{S}$ to $\mathbb{S}$. I'm not sure if it's possible in this setting to define the degree - remember $\mathbb{S}$ is the unit sphere in an infinite dimensional Banach space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer my own question after all:

Define $M_t$ mapping $C^2(\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2)$ to itself by
$$
M_t = P + [P + L^{-1} \circ (I - P)] \circ F_t
$$
where
$$
P(X) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{S}^1} X ds
$$
is the projection onto $\ker L$ via the splitting $C^2(\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2) \simeq \ker L \oplus \operatorname{R}(L)$. Then $I - P$ is the projection onto $\operatorname{R}(L)$. Thus $L^{-1} \circ (I - P) \circ G$ is well defined and there's no need to restrict to any subspaces like $Z$ in the  original question.

Then it's straight forward to show that
$$
L(X) = F_t(X)
$$
if and only if
$$
X = M_t(X)
$$
and hence I just need to study the degree of $M_t$.

This construction may be found in:

"The Leray-Schauder degree of $S^1$-equivariant operators associated to autonomous neutral equations in spaces of periodic functions"
Journal of Differential Equations,
Volume 92, Issue 1,
1991,
Pages 90-99,
ISSN 0022-0396,
https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-0396(91)90065-H